Android Pie (9) debug in android studio
Why cannot i debug my apps in android pie ?, pie just 'offline', but nougat is work, thank you.


The offline one just replug the usb cable.

i have replugged my usb cable, i have changed my usb cable, i have plugged my cable usb in other port usb, and all still don't work until now.

can someone help me?

Same problem here

CASE CLOSE and  case close
